# Stop word-wrap dividing words

Tags: css, uiwebview, word-wrap

```
body { word-wrap: break-word;}
```

I've been using that code (above) to fit the text in the `body` into it's container. However what I don't like about it, is that it breaks up words.

Is there another way where it will not break up words and only line break after or before a word?

EDIT: This is for use within a `UIWebView`.

Comment: What do you suppose "break-word" means?

Comment: I knew that, but I say "Is there another way".

Comment: alas `word-wrap: normal;` doesn't help. Nor does `white-space: wrap;` alone help if you are trying to wrap words in a table cell (my situation).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

use `white-space: nowrap;`. If you have set width on the element on which you are setting this it should work.

update -
rendered data in Firefox
[image]

Comment: Nope, still nothing. This code still displays the full text with horizontal scrollbar. `body { width: 768px; white-space: wrap;}`

Comment: just setting width takes care of wrapping the text a you need(atleast on firefox). can you check behaviours on specific browsers and update the post

Comment: i have updated my answer to include rendered result on firefox.

Comment: This still does not work for me, I've edited my question to say what browser this is for.

Comment: Actually got it working now! Was accidentally overriding the width without noticing!

Comment: wrap is an invalid property value

Comment: This should not be the correct answer, `white-space: wrap;` isn't a valid property value

Comment: It's `white-space: nowrap` actually.

Comment: 1: This doesn't work. 2: Terrible screenshot - don't bother next time if this is the quality. Better: Just post a `jsfiddle`, or online debugger next time. It would have shown you (and everyone else) this doesn't work as you describe. Example of how this does NOT work: https://jsfiddle.net/9dfpyvxk/ -> You really think adjusting the "global" BODY WIDTH is a feasible fix for this? BODY WIDTH affects entire page.

Answer (score 32):

I had the same problem, I solved it using following css:

```
.className {
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  word-break:break-word;
}
```

Comment: Third answer is the one that actually answers the question. Both accepted and second answer will cause the text to not wrap at all.

Answer (score 30):

Please use nowrap and wrap value didn't come for me. nowrap solved the issue.

```css
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: This prevents a word from breaking - but it also prevents the whole line of text from breaking.

Answer (score 28):

May be a bit late but you can add this css to stop word breaks:

```
.element {
    -webkit-hyphens: none;
    -moz-hyphens:    none;
    -ms-hyphens:     none;
    hyphens:         none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**You can try this...**

```
body{
white-space: pre; /* CSS2 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
white-space: -hp-pre-wrap; /* HP printers */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS 2.1 */
white-space: pre-line; /* CSS 3 (and 2.1 as well, actually) */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
}
```

{word-wrap:;} is an IE proprietary property, and not a part of css. firefox's handling is correct. Unfortunately, FF does not support a soft hyphen / . so that's not an option. You could possibly insert a hair or thin space,  /  (check me on the numeric entity) and  / , respectively.

Making **{overflow: hidden;}** would cut the overflow off, and **{overflow: auto;}** would cause the overflow to enable scrolling.

Comment: None of the examples you gave me actually work, the only one that does is `word-wrap`.

Comment: alternative is {overflow: hidden;} and {overflow: auto;} but there is a problem to that as well.

Comment: Yeh, but that isn't what I'm looking for as `overflow: hidden;` would hide everything off the edge. :/

Comment: This does not answer the question - which is how to prevent word breaks.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the parent was smaller than the word. Adding will break on spaces, but not words :

```
    word-break: initial;
```

Answer (score 3):

To stop words from breaking, **you should unset `word-break`**. The default is `normal`, which allows word breaks but at break points.

`overflow-wrap` controls when word breaks happen.

### You should instead set the `overflow-wrap` property to `always` to break words only when they are too long to fit on a line (instead of overflowing).

The default `normal` to disable word breaks, allowing words too long to overflow the edge of the element.

If your element width is flexible (e.g. min-width, or display:flex), and you want too expand the element instead of line breaking, you can use the value `break-word`.

The property `word-break` determines whether words should only break at break points, or always (when they could overflow).

[Helpful info and demo on overflow-wrap - MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

[Info on word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Further things:

- *If you want to disable **all** word breaks, even when it can't line break, i.e. japanese text, you can use the `word-break: keep-all`*
- *The value `break-word` may have been unsupported and is now deprecated, as is the `word-wrap` CSS property (initially added by MS for this same function).

Comment: This was very helpful for a project in which the prior developers applied this CSS rule to the `body` element without me realizing it.

Answer (score 2):

In my situation I am trying to ensure words wrap at proper word-breaks within table cells.

I found I need the following CSS to achieve this.

```
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
}
td {
  white-space: wrap;
}
```

also check that nothing else is changing `word-break` to `break-word` instead of `normal`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `white-space: nowrap;`

CSS white-space Property

`white-space: normal|nowrap|pre|pre-line|pre-wrap|initial|inherit;`

[Know more about white-space example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_white-space)

Answer (score 1):

Word break issue on Firefox browser. So you can use to prevent word-break:

```
-webkit-hyphens: none;
-moz-hyphens: none;
hyphens: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this Code for our website to stop the word-breaking:

```
body {
    -ms-hyphens: none;
    -webkit-hyphens: none;
    hyphens: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.className {
    hyphens: none;
    word-break: keep-all;
}
```

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was setting [overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) to normal:

```
overflow-wrap: normal;
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar problem in my grid structure and I used, word-break: break-word;
in my grid and my issue got resolved.

Comment: There's no `break-word` value for `word-break` property.

Comment: This does not answer the question - which is how to prevent word breaks.

Answer (score -1):

This helped me with old Webkit - this one from phantomjs 2.1

```
.table td {
    overflow-wrap: break-spaces;
    word-break: normal;
}
```