# How to disable word breaking in CSS?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

How to disable breaking words into parts when wrapping lines in CSS? For example, currently, if it has no space, it writes word "impossible" in the following way:

```
I think it is not im-
possible
```

i would like it write

```
I think it is not
impossible
```

i.e. wrap entire word "impossible" to next line, not only part of it.

I don't wish to change text alignment.

**UPDATE**

The answer proposed here: [Stop word-wrap dividing words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775810/stop-word-wrap-dividing-words) look irrational or tricky, because `white-space` property has no  possible value of `wrap`, described here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Also, the overall topic of `white-space` is different and described as "specifies how white-space inside an element is handled" (see link above).

So, I can't regard the answer about `white-space` as correct and/or duplicate.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp (5s on google)

Comment: Do you have a `word-break: break-all` anywhere in your CSS? Please show us your code as I don't think what you have posted is the default behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop word-wrap dividing words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775810/stop-word-wrap-dividing-words)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I was confused by "duplicate" question and it's clones, reproducing strange approach with `white-space` property

Comment: @Dims What do you mean?

Answer (score 16):

[`word-break: keep-all;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) will keep words whole.

Comment: This looks the only reasonable answer.

Comment: and [supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_word-break_keep-all)

Answer (score 3):

I consider wrong solution the "white-space" with "nowrap" or "pre" too, it is not doing the correct behaviour.
The text should break lines, but not break words. This is caused by some css attributes: **word-wrap, overflow-wrap, word-break, hyphens**. So you can have either:

```
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

Remove them, or override them with "unset" or "normal":

```
word-break: unset;
word-wrap: unset;
overflow-wrap: unset;
-webkit-hyphens: unset;
-moz-hyphens: unset;
-ms-hyphens: unset;
hyphens: unset;
```

JSfiddle provided: https://jsfiddle.net/azozp8rr/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is useful in your scenario but it sure will stop a word from braking: **white-space: nowrap;**

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean:

```
.word {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

Comment: I did and `word-wrap` fit's the best. `word-break` would break it to `i{NEWLINE}mpossible` (Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break) and the way I testet `word-wrap` works like he wanted. There is a chance I missunderstood the question, but lets wait for more input from the creator.

Comment: Read again. OP doesn't want the work to break. The question is poorly worded, but it comes across as pretty clear to me.