# Paragraph in div is not breaking word using CSS

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

**Problem:**

[image]

Check Here, [Sample Page With CSS Problem](https://progresif.sajilni.com/event/test-event-6272) and here is a [VIDEO](https://res.cloudinary.com/shareefhiasat/video/upload/v1565764742/video_of_break_word_problem_picpht.mp4) to explain the problem

**Details Of Problem:**

Am using [ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/demo/) to fill my content, but looks that word wrapping
is conflicting with WYSIWYG from *CKEditor*...

If I put in *CKEditor* long line, I expect it gets word-wrapped smoothly.

But what I have is random *break-word* works on 95% of my cases!

**What I Tried:**

I tried and researched but each time there is a case
where it just won't work for some scenarios!.

[stackoverflow break-word question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775810/stop-word-wrap-dividing-words)

[CSS tricks and tips](https://css-tricks.com/where-lines-break-is-complicated-heres-all-the-related-css-and-html/)

Can this be a browser problem or?

Comment: Please produce a [mcve] HERE with expected output

Comment: it is reproducable, just go to https://progresif.sajilni.com/event/test-event-6272 and use inspector just like i shown in the video here  https://res.cloudinary.com/shareefhiasat/video/upload/v1565764742/video_of_break_word_problem_picpht.mp4 you will see the words is not wrapped, you can play with that page using developer tools !

Comment: Are the `&nbsp;` between each word always generated? If so, that would seem like a problem with the CKEditor. Sometimes formatting is messed up when copying text from a document into an editor. Is that the case here?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier yes you are right, any suggestions to work this around, smart and smoothly for general cases at least thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this script anywhere on your page. It will manually remove all the `&nbsp;` characters found in all elements inside the `.event-text` container and replaces them with spaces.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.event-text *');
    texts.forEach(text => text.innerText = text.innerText.replace(/\u00a0/g, ' '));
});
```

This is a hack, not a permanent solution. I strongly advise you to contact the folks at CKEditor and ask them for a fix.

For more detailed other options with CKEditor configuration,[ckeditor unwanted nbsp characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741620/ckeditor-unwanted-nbsp-characters) you may check

Comment: thanks for pushing my thinking into right direction, i have used that hack and it works, better you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741620/ckeditor-unwanted-nbsp-characters

Comment: jquery solution for me `$(".event-text").html($(".event-text").html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' '));`

Answer (score 0):

@shareef you need to remove all **&nbsp** then you need to use **word-break: break-word;** in your **p** tag

Comment: cant do, my only option is with the div because as i said am using CKEditor and those p is auto-generated ( i can't control)

Comment: @shareef if you add **padding-right:0;** of **.event-instructions** element then your paragraph will be break and show.