# Timeline - overlap text?

Tags: html, css

I have created timeline, but i have problem with overlap text.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lkn8qda0/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div id="timeline">
      <div>
        <section class="year" *ngFor="let d of data">
          <h3>PARTIALLY ACCEPTED/REJECTED</h3>
          <section>
            <ul>
              <li>20.01.2020}</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my fiddle,but i dont know how to fix problem when text is longer.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `white-space: wrap;` to avoid breaks in the middle of words, see [this older discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775810/stop-word-wrap-dividing-words). But this will treat "ACCEPTED/REJECTED" as one word, so you would probably want to add whitespace characters there, like "ACCEPTED / REJECTED".

[This article](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-control-white-space-in-text-with-css-2a7695a0c73b) has an extensive explanation of text wrapping possibilities and strategies in CSS.